# Starting a Particle System in Unity with Buttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Hello everyone I made a rocket fire partical with Unity's partical system but Idk how can I make it activated when I press my thrust engine button (W and up Arrow is my buttons)
This is my code;

```
public class Rocket : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    
    public float amount;
    public float MaxVelocity = 3;
    public float RotationSpeed = 3;

    




    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


    }

    public void ThrustForward(float amount)
    {
        Vector2 force = transform.up * amount;

        rb.AddForce(force);
        
   

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float Yaxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float Xaxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

       
        ThrustForward(Yaxis);
        Rotate(transform, Xaxis * RotationSpeed);
         

    }   
    private void ClampVelocity()
    {
        float x = Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.x, -MaxVelocity, MaxVelocity);
        float y = Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.y, -MaxVelocity, MaxVelocity);

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(x, y);
      

    }


   

    private void Rotate(Transform t,float amount)
    {
        t.Rotate(0, 0, amount);
     
    }
   

}
```

Please help me how can I start a particle system in unity with buttons
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You Have A Particle System, You Can Make A Variable In Your Code  Like, Following:

```
public ParticleSystem particle;
```

You Can Play The Particle System By Using The Variable With .Play() in end, for example, if you have created a variable like above as I suggested, you can play the particle system whenever you want.


The Way We Do It Is Pretty Simple.

```
particle.Play();
```

## Direct Solution

Remove Everything From Your Script And Try Overwriting  It With Following Code

```
public class Rocket : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public ParticleSystem particle;
    public float amount;
    public float MaxVelocity = 3;
    public float RotationSpeed = 3;

    




    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


    }

    public void ThrustForward(float amount)
    {
        Vector2 force = transform.up * amount;

        rb.AddForce(force);
        particle.Play();
        
   

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float Yaxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float Xaxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

       
        ThrustForward(Yaxis);
        Rotate(transform, Xaxis * RotationSpeed);


       // You Can Do Exactly Same Thing For Arrow Key
       // To Get Better Rusults Try Messing With The Particle System's Settings

      
            
       

         




    }   
    private void ClampVelocity()
    {
        float x = Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.x, -MaxVelocity, MaxVelocity);
        float y = Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.y, -MaxVelocity, MaxVelocity);

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(x, y);
      

    }


   

    private void Rotate(Transform t,float amount)
    {
        t.Rotate(0, 0, amount);
     
    }
   

}
```

Comment: I Try to use Particle.Play(); but I can't understand where should I put –

Comment: At Point Where You Want It. For Example If When User press a key  then you can give two brackets with syntax of looking for input, you can use particle.play in there.

Comment: I use Direct solutio but When I press "W" it dissapears and when I am not pressing "W" particle starts so This code do opposite thing I want :)

Comment: Something Might Be Wrong With Particle System.. Select Particle System Make Sure It Not Set To Play On Awake And Loop Is Disabled

Comment: no it isn't workin I turn off looping and play on awake but still same problem

Comment: That's how it works. there might be something wrong with particle system, anyways i changed script try it again